# Maybe a type in typescript

Tags: typescript, haskell, functional-programming

I would like to construct a `Maybe a` type in typescript a la Haskell:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

It seems like the way to do it in `typescript` is:

```
interface Nothing { tag "Nothing }
type Maybe<T> = T | Nothing
```

I would like to make a function:

```
function foo(x : string) : Maybe<T> {
    return Nothing
}
```

akin to:

```
foo : String -> Maybe a
foo _ = Nothing
```

However this does not work in `typescript`. What is the right way to return a value `Nothing` in typescript? I would like to avoid using `null` if possible.

___________________________________________________-

Edit: It would be really *nice* if the function `foo` would return a *value* `Nothing` because I would like to pattern match on value constructor later, ie:

```
case blah blah of 
    | Just x -> x + x
    | Nothing -> "no words"
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [FP TS](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/), in particular its [`Option` type](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/Option.html).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall thanks that kind of resources is just what I'm looking for

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depending on the case, it can be `void`, `undefined`, or `?` optional modifier for properties and parameters.

It's:

```
function foo(x : string) : number | void {
    // returns nothing
}
```

`void` and `undefined` types are compatible, but there is some difference between them. The former is preferable for function return types, because the latter requires a function to have `return` statement:

```
function foo(x : string) : number | undefined {
    return;
}
```

`Maybe` can be implemented with generic type. Explicit `Nothing` type can be implemented with unique symbol:

```
const Nothing = Symbol('nothing');
type Nothing = typeof Nothing;
type Maybe<T> = T | Nothing;

function foo(x : string) : Maybe<number> {
    return Nothing;
}
```

Or a class (private fields can be used to prevent ducktyping):

```
abstract class Nothing {
    private tag = 'nothing'
}
type Maybe<T> = T | typeof Nothing;

function foo(x : string) : Maybe<number> {
    return Nothing;
}
```

Notice that class types designate class instance type and require to use `typeof` when a class is referred.

Or an object (if duck typing can be desirable):

```
const Nothing: { tag: 'Nothing' } = { tag: 'Nothing' };
type Nothing = typeof Nothing;
type Maybe<T> = T | Nothing;

function foo(x : string) : Maybe<number> {
    return Nothing;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for it to return  a value `Nothing`? Becaues I would like to pattern match on the value later

Comment: I'm not familiar with Haskell. What exactly do you mean? You can compare a value against `undefined`.

Comment: this blog gives a good intro: https://blog.carbonfive.com/2018/01/08/an-introduction-to-adts-and-structural-pattern-matching-in-typescript/   Basically pattern matching determine which case you are in.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the real benefit in comparison with undefined. If you need 'nothing but not undefined', that's the use case for null. undefined or null is idiomatic JS/TS approach. You can use symbols for that https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20Nothing%20%3D%20Symbol(%27nothing%27)%3B%0D%0Atype%20Nothing%20%3D%20typeof%20Nothing%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(x%20%3A%20string)%20%3A%20number%20%7C%20Nothing%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%7D but there may be shortcomings.

Comment: Or use a plain object if you can benefit from structural compatibility, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20Nothing%3A%20%7B%20tag%3A%20%27Nothing%27%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20tag%3A%20%27Nothing%27%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Nothing%20%3D%20typeof%20Nothing%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(x%20%3A%20string)%20%3A%20number%20%7C%20Nothing%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Nothing%3B%0D%0A%7D

Comment: I listed all the options. Hope this helps.

Comment: @EstusFlask In case you're interested, the crucial benefit of `Maybe` in Haskell is how you can or cannot use the result of the `foo` function. With a type of `Maybe<T>`, the Haskell type system forces you to check whether the value is `undefined`/`Nothing` before you try to use it as a `T`. (Checking whether there's a value is what OP meant by "case matching" in this case.) Your first example appears to work. (See my link below for the code.)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAciKALAlmA5jAvDAygTwFsAjEAGwAoByMRVDKgSgG4BYAKCnwAcBTeOmkw4ufEADMByIW049+AWQCG+YrwA8AFQB82GJpgAfKfXSyO4gK5hgUFOBjiQICgA8YALhjQATkMaeMMqqGmCWJLw+ugDeHDDxMD68UJY+YCYyHAC+HBwA9HkwoJCwhPgAakpklvxeYRE+ek4uAERIvGRkIC0BBTAAYkooZBAwUCBj8sDtwADWAHT6SEpQVKMA7suw6-zrSmBQuex9ABIgOwBukQA0Y+1JMGC8vAAmo+MwajBKMHv4YxNeK4oD4lLY7vx6mpGqJ+Ep0EMwPMOGRkoleBBLGRYDhmhQ2h0uj0OChJBRYRJ0ZjsdgcC0oZEejBYux4n0ktTtkpRj8LlUasxHudbjsivtfiAfLNfihkBCYHzqrw4kVwNAYGVKkrAgzGjgOVjDqyYH15mbsjAOhB+Cy2YUDTS9qMENIMIsACKAnw+SUwZZgF5kIS3bg+l6WYBwmAvXjiJSGhX83i3ZLAZHsLJAA

Comment: I suppose Haskell's pattern matching with case statements is roughly equivalent to TypeScript's [equality matching with switch statements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#equality-narrowing). In the context of `Maybe<T>`, they're both narrowing the type from `T | Nothing` to either `T` or `Nothing`.

Answer (score 4):

```
enum Nothing {
  Nothing = 'Nothing'
}

type Maybe<A> = A | Nothing
type MaybeNumber = Maybe<number>

const isNothing = (m: MaybeNumber): m is Nothing => m === Nothing.Nothing 

const foo = (m: MaybeNumber) => {
  if (isNothing(m)) {
    return Nothing.Nothing
  } else {
    return m + 1
  }
}

foo(1) // ✔️
foo('Nothing') // ❌
foo(Nothing.Nothing) // ✔️
```

or without using an `enum` using a `string literal type`

```
const Nothing = '__nothing__'

type Maybe<A> = A | Nothing
type MaybeNumber = Maybe<number>

const isNothing = (m: MaybeNumber): m is Nothing => m === Nothing 

const foo = (m: MaybeNumber) => {
  if (isNothing(m)) {
    return Nothing
  } else {
    return m + 1
  }
}

foo(1) // ✔️
foo(Nothing) // ✔️
foo('__nothing__') // ✔️
```

or with symbols

```
const nothing = Symbol('Nothing')
type Nothing = typeof nothing

type Maybe<A> = A | Nothing
type MaybeNumber = Maybe<number>

const isNothing = (m: MaybeNumber): m is Nothing => m.toString() === 'Symbol(Nothing)' 

const foo = (m: MaybeNumber) => {
  if (isNothing(m)) {
    return nothing
  } else {
    return m + 1
  }
}

foo(1) // ✔️
foo(nothing) // ✔️
```

live on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-maybe)